# I can not connect to postgres database

Tags: node.js, postgresql, express, sequelize.js

When trying to connect to the database

Me connectig property:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize("postgres", "postgres", "postgres", {
  dialect: "postgres",
  host: "127.0.0.1",
  port: "5432",
});
```

Server setting:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ahsgT.png)

Error:

```
{ SequelizeConnectionError: ������������ "postgres" �� ������ �������� ����������� (�� ������)
    at connection.connect.err (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\sequelize\lib\dialects\postgres\connection-manager.js:182:24)
    at Connection.connectingErrorHandler (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\pg\lib\client.js:174:14)
    at Connection.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (E:\Dropbox\BigDeal\BigDealExpressJSTest\node_modules\pg\lib\connection.js:126:12)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:189:13)
    at addChunk (_stream_readable.js:284:12)
    at readableAddChunk (_stream_readable.js:265:11)
    at Socket.Readable.push (_stream_readable.js:220:10)
    at TCP.onStreamRead [as onread] (internal/stream_base_commons.js:94:17)
  name: 'SequelizeConnectionError',
```

How to fix it?

Answer (score 4):

I only used Sequelize once some time ago, but that's how I initialized it.:

```
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    database: 'project-db',
    username: 'postgres',
    password: 'postgres',
    host: 'localhost',
    port: 5432,
    dialect: 'postgres'
});
```

EDIT:

Reading the Sequelize documentation it seems your way to connect should also work. Are you sure "postgres" (the first parameter) is the name of an existing database?

Comment: I see the image you uploaded and that the database exists but I think you did an edit request to my answer by mistake instead of editing your question. In any case, I see it exists and it seems to be started and working properly. I don't know what else to suggest...